# PDF Generation in VB.net coding environment.... using iText

Tags: vb.net, pdf-generation, itext

I just realized the OLD tutorial here is still works.
Here is the webpage [link](http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/en/download.html)

But that one is iText 2005.
And now is 2011, I wonder if there's any nearest version of iText for vb.net ? 
I didn't found the iText for vb.net in 2008 version....

is there anyone could clarify this?
Because that 2005 version is using .Net framework 1 or 2.
Very old... now I'm using version 3 & 4.

correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

iText VB is dead. You could use [iText Sharp 5.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), that's the current latest version